# Why is there no Stack Exchange site dedicated to Q&A about "Hacking"?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

Why is there no Stack Exchange site dedicated to Q&A about *Hacking*? Is this topic included in any other site? Where can I ask about this topic?

Comment: Explain what you mean by ["hacking"](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/meaning-of-hack.html). Do you mean ["cracking"](http://catb.org/jargon/html/C/cracker.html)?

Comment: Aneesh - be aware that Sec.SE will not teach you how to be a "hacker" so questions on that topic will be closed very quickly.

Comment: Brought the -1 back up to zero because of an apparent rush-to-judgement.  Hacking has become a field _somewhat_ distinct from security in that security is an umbrella term for prevention.  Hacking is a far more indepth specialty which would breed the very best in counter-hacking engineering---a pioneering discipline far beyond the ability of most security folks.  Really, while perhaps once it was sensible to, today it's not to be confused with mere security.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is [Information Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) which might answer your queries

> Information Security Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for
>   information security professionals.

And there was a proposal in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) related to hacking and pen testing but it didn't get much response.

[Hacking Q&A proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104902/hacking-penetration-testing) and the [relevant discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26030/do-we-need-a-hacking-site).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to InfoSec SE, there is also [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) for "researchers and developers who explore the principles of a computer system through analysis of its structure, function, and operation."

On-topic questions include looking at executables files under-the-hood and packet and firmware analytics for a wide variety of platforms.

Just know that general "hacking" questions (whatever that means) would be off-topic.  Reverse Engineering SE is for **specific issues and real problems**, not general or broad questions.